# Op Amp Circuit with Transistor. Not seeing what I expect in simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, current-source

I found a design that was used a current source. I have simulated it, and it doesn't appear to behave as expected. I expect the V+ and V- to be equal, but they are not.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

[image: Op Amp Circuit]

Comment: Remove the 5k1 resistor and increase V4

Answer (score 1):

The LM324 is saturated at the positive rail, only 1.4mA base current is flowing and the beta of Q1 is only 100 so it cannot produce 3.3V at V-. The LM324 cannot do any more.

To make it work, try reducing the 5.1K resistor. Calculate what it must be in order to work within your requirements and make it a bit less that that.

There's also a 2:1 voltage divider so there has to be 6.6V at the emitter, which is not possible with a 3.3V supply (Q1 will saturate). So you have to increase the 3.3V supply to the collector. If you don't the op-amp will try to supply the current through the base resistor and, if the resistor is low enough, will short-circuit current limit and get hot inside.

Note that the (fairly) constant current when this circuit is working is in the collector of Q1, not the emitter, so typically you'd want to minimize the voltage across R5, and divide down the input voltage to suit. For example, you might make it 200mV, which is relatively high compared to op-amp offset voltage and offset voltage drift.

If you are trying to get a constant current through R5, this circuit does not do that, even with corrections. Rather it can only provide a constant  voltage across R5, so the current will be proportional to 1/R5.

Comment: You'll need to get 6.6V across R5 so V4 is going to have to go higher too.